# Why turning velocity of star towards point "A" makes it's satelites, change their apoapsis to side opposite of velocity vector?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, simulations, celestial-mechanics

Why turning velocity of star towards point "A" makes it's satelites, change their apoapsis to side opposite of velocity vector?

Sentence above turned a bit crazy or not understandable (possible reasons: my vocabulary isn't that good; I don't know what the heck I am talking about).

So I mean this: http://phet.colorado.edu/sims/my-solar-system/my-solar-system_en.html The first you get is star (yellow) and planet (purple). If you closely, you notice circle around star. It's velocity, if you move it in direction opposite to purple star. Purple planet get's crazy and flies away, as if star turns it's magnetic polar towards that planet.

Comment: This question is hard (impossible?) to understand unless you post the exact settings for the scenario that's puzzling you. What are the readings in the yellow and pink boxes?

Comment: Reload page. Drag velocity of yellow circle. Away from purple circle. Why does purple circle fly away so badly? - It's as simple as possible.

Comment: So, essentially, what you mean is the standard settings but with `body 1`'s velocity set to -50 or something suitably large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opposite sign of the shifts is due to the conservation of the location of the center-of-mass or, equivalently, momentum conservation.

At least for the simple system of 2 bodies, the animation on the page is being observed from the inertial frame of the center of mass. One may check this fact by seeing that the trajectories are periodic (ellipses) even if the masses are comparable and the initial velocities and locations are generic (but allowing a bound state).

In the center-of-mass frame, the total momentum of both bodies is zero. So if one of them moves in one direction, the other is moving in the opposite direction. Their trajectories are really ellipses that are similar to each other (one obtains one from another by scaling, multiplication by a negative number). It follows that if the apsis of one body is on one side from the center of mass, the apsis of the other body must be on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the standard view tends to follow the centre of the system, and therefore the more massive body. You can stop this behaviour by de-selecting the `System centered` checkbox. You'll see essentially the same behaviour for the planet (purple), while the star (yellow) goes off to the left.

[image]